Which gamma (ratio of specific heats) impacts optimal nozzle throat area, gamma in the chamber or the throat?
In order to determine the nozzle throat area of a liquid rocket engine, Sutton's equation for this is very helpful: the one dependent on mass flow rate, chamber pressure/temperature, and gamma (ratio of specific heats). However, between the gamma of the chamber and the gamma at the throat, which one should be considered when sizing the throat area?

To prevent confusion, can you reproduce the exact equation you're asking about or provide a link to it? Is it the one in this question? https://space.stackexchange.com/q/34711/6944
